# Which X509 StoreName refers to the certificates stored beneath Trusted Root Certification Authorities in Windows10

Tags: ssl, client-certificates, x509certificate2

When enumerating the `AuthRoot` and `CertificateAuthorities` X509 stores, I have been unable to find a self-signed SSL certificate that was imported into `Trusted Root Certification Authorities` on the local machine:

```
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.AuthRoot);  // also tried StoreName.CertificateAuthorities
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        var storecollection = (X509Certificate2Collection) store.Certificates;
        foreach (X509Certificate2 x509 in storecollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("certificate name: {0}", x509.Subject);
        }
```

Are self-signed SSL certificates skipped over as invalid by the enumerator? Am I looking in the wrong place?

Here's what I see in the Certificates snap-in in MMC:

[image: MMC Certificates snap-in]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`StoreName.Root` is what you want for "Trusted Root Certification Authorities".

`AuthRoot` is "Third-Party Root Certification Authorities", and `CertificateAuthority` is "Intermediate Certification Authorities".